# How to prove a claim stating that there are lots of real numbers which are not rational.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Dear reader of this post,

I am trying to prove a claim stating that there are lots of real numbers which are not rational. Unfortunately, I do not know whether I should use a constructive proof or show the contrapositive because I do not know how to deal with some elements of the conditional statement when pursuing either strategy.

The claim is as follows: If $a $ is a positive integer such that $a \neq b^2$ for any $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ then there is no rational number $r$ such that $r^2 = a$.

I tried a constructive prove at first. However, I am stumbling when using the statement $a \neq b^2$. Afterwards, I tried to prove the contrapositive but I cannot negate the hypothesis. I rewrote the conditional statement in term of quantifiers as:
\begin{equation*}
\text{If} \ ( \exists a \in \mathbb{Z}_{++}: a \neq b^{2} \ \forall b \in \mathbb{Z}), \text{then} \ ( \not \exists r \in \mathbb{Q}: r^{2} = a). 
\end{equation*}
I think the negation of the conclusion is $\exists r \in \mathbb{Q}: r^{2} = a$.

I would like to ask the following questions:

- Is the negation of the conclusion correct? What is the negation of the hypothesis?
- How can one deal with the statement $a \neq b^2$ in the hypothesis when doing a constructive prof?

I am looking forward for your replies.

Comment: How do you do a *constructive* proof that something does *not* exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you are trying to prove (talking about the secondary claim) that if the equation $x^2 - a = 0$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$, then it has no solutions in $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e. it is irreducible, since we are working with a degree 2 polynomial). This follows from the more general fact, Gauss's lemma. This is an elementary fact that would probably be worth knowing now (but see below for something more hands on).

Also your original question can be answered from a cardinality perspective entirely (look up the diagonalization argument)

You're first bullet point is correct!

Write $x = \frac{a}{b}$. wlog they are coprime. What do you get? (this generalizes to the rational root theorem, but don't look up the proof!).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose by contradiction that there exist two coprime integers $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a= \frac{c^2}{d^2}$, that is $ad^2=c^2$. Now compare the [p-adic orders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $ad^2$ and $c^2$ (more precisely their parity).